# go to Page url eliminating slashes when passed to client side function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In a View Simply on button click a url should be open in new tab. Same works well with anchor tag but when applied to button tag it works strange eliminating the slashes from url, Url saved in DB is like this..

> > Uploads\Donor\Pages\man Khan_6e48.html

this works fine

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/"+@post.PostPageLink)" target="_blank" class="item-photo item-photo--static">
```

Result.

```
https://localhost:44360/Uploads/Donor/Pages/man%20Khan_6e48.html
```

but when try these...

```
<button  onclick="ViewPostPage('@Url.Content("~/"+@post.PostPageLink)')" class="properties__pay">View @post.Category Post</button>

function ViewPostPage(pagelink) {
    alert(pagelink);
    window.open(pagelink);
};
```

or

```
<button  onClick="parent.open('../@post.PostPageLink')" class="properties__pay">View @post.Category Post</button>
```

page url results like this...

```
https://localhost:44360/UploadsDonorPagesman%20Khan_6e48.html
```

whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor inside the button,

```
<button class="properties__pay">
   <a href=`'~/'${@post.PostPageLink}` target="_blank">
      `View ${@post.Category} Post`
   </a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the browser thinks you are escaping all the characters after `\`.
You need to escape the `\`. You can use `encodeURIComponent` from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) example.

Answer (score 0):

that's what solved the prob..

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/"+@post.PostPageLink)" target="_blank">
                                                        <button class="properties__pay">View @post.Category Post</button>
                                                    </a>
```